# c# all label detect one function-void

Tags: c#, algorithm, forms, if-statement, label

I'm going to make a simple maze game in C#. In the picture box, the visual keyboard will go up, down, left and right, there is no problem here.

Going to the starting point when touching the labels with event autosize true. When I have 100 labels, I don't want to write 100 ifs.

If the Picturebox does the following on any label (below);

```
if (pictureBox1.Right >= label1.Left && pictureBoxl.Bottom >= label1.Top)
{
   if (pictureBox1.Left <= label1.Right && pictureBoxl.Top <= label1.Bottom)
   {
       //pictureBox1 and label1 touching
   }
}
```

Label1 above will be checked for all labels. this is what i want

How can I do that.

Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add all the labels to an array and check them in a `for` loop:

1.Declare a global array:

```
Label[] myLabels;
```

2. Initialize `myLabel` array in `InitializeComponent`:

```
myLabels= new Label[] {label1, label2, ... };
```

3. Check in a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myLabels.Length; i++)
{
   if (pictureBox1.Right >= myLabels[i].Left && pictureBoxl.Bottom >= myLabels[i].Top)
   {
      if (pictureBox1.Left <= myLabels[i].Right && pictureBoxl.Top <= myLabels[i].Bottom)
      {
          //pictureBox1 and myLabels[i] touching
          return;
      }
   }
}
```